# Preprocessor macro with commas in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm working through the arcsynthesis OpenGL tutorial, which makes regular use of macros, something that I've been reading I should avoid when possible. I'm wondering if there is another way of doing the following without filling in the values manually (or if that is what I should do):

```
#define GREEN_COLOR 0.75f, 0.75f, 1.0f, 1.0f

const float vertexData[] = {
    ..., //Vertex positions

    GREEN_COLOR,
    GREEN_COLOR,
    GREEN_COLOR,

    ..., //Rest of the colors
}
```

Comment: It's still unclear what you are trying to do with this macro.  Are you just trying to automate the creation of the array to have those values?

Comment: Pretty much, which would create a single place to change the value for green, instead of having to edit it in multiple places.

Comment: I can't think of an easier way to do this at the top of my head. To alleviate your concerns about macro's, you could `#undef GREEN_COLOR` right after vertexData has been declared; that way it serves its purpose, but can't be abused later on.

Comment: Okay, that would work. GREEN_COLOR can probably stay the same, but if I want to do it with another concept this would be good to know.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor doesn't care about commas, spaces, *etc*.  It treats them as any other character and simply does a text substitution with them.  The only thing to watch out for are newlines, but a trailing `\` at the end of the line takes care of them too.  For example:

```
#define GREEN_COLOR 0.75f,\
                    0.75f,\
                    1.0f, \
                    1.0f
```

Comment: Okay, perhaps this is one of those times that macros work best.

Comment: @bitrayne there s more if u dig into boost source code headers